# How do I put hardware dependencies on .deb packages?

Tags: deb, cpu-architecture

Building deb packages optimized for arbitrary CPU instructions, how do I put the CPU instructions as a dependency on the deb packages ?
The package isn't intended for mass distribution, but I don't want to have people confused with crashes because their CPU is too old for my builds.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the sort of restriction you're talking about?  Typically `dpkg-buildpackage` will pick your current architecture, but this may not be fine grained enough for your needs.

Comment: If I use "-march=amdfam10", guy with a old core2 without SSE4 won't be able to run my build without fatal errors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure the `dpkg` format, itself, can do what you require.

However you *can* make use of *preinstall* scripts.  In this you can test to see if the CPU is of the right level and abort if it is not good enough.  In this way your package won't install.

The `preinst` script is part of the `control` section of a pkg; you can read about it at https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-pkg_basics.en.html

These are sometimes called *preinstall sanity scripts*.  If they end with a non-zero exit code then the package install fails.

Your `preinst` script could be as simple as

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

flags=`grep ^flags /proc/cpuinfo | head -1`

if [ -z "`echo $flags | grep sse4`" ]
then
  echo Can only run on machines with SSE4 instructions.  Install failed
  exit 1
fi

exit 0
```

Comment: Preinstall scripts are the place to do hardware tests, I have done a lot of hardware based scripting in gnu/linux, and particularly debian, and it's always astounded me that the package maintainers absolutely refuse to do hardware testing in the install scripts, even though the logic is all out there in the world, available and ready to go. You want the failure, as stephen says, to occur before the package can be installed, and ideally, you want everything to be returned to pre install state after showing the message of failure, clear language that explains why it was rejected.

Comment: @lizardx if you have a concrete example implementation of such a preinst script it would make for a really good answer.

Comment: @GnP how would you determine the CPU was adequate?  It could be as simple is `if [ -z ! $(grep myrequiredstuff /proc/cpuinfo)]; then exit 1; fi`

Comment: gnp, hardware is specific, so you have to provide the exact data or it's a waste of time and energy. However, stephen is again correct, it's all in /proc/cpuinfo on linux kernel running systems. getting cpu flags is trivial. grep ^flags /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'your flags'. Install scripts are just bash files as far as I know, or sh, I forget, never got into packaging.

Comment: @StephenHarris For sake of completeness, could you add to the answer an exemple script that will check for two CPU instruction and where to place the script ? (as not shown on the manual link)

Comment: See example for how to check for SSE4 enabled processors.

Comment: @StephenHarris I'm genuinely curious — where have you seen this referred to as "preinstall sanity scripts"?

Comment: @Lizardx there are `preinst` scripts in Debian which check for hardware support (see [here](https://codesearch.debian.net/search?q=cpuinfo+path%3Adebian%2F.*preinst)). The usual objections when this kind of thing comes up *for inclusion in Debian* is that there are better, more generic approaches (such as `ld.so` capabilities) that don't involve blowing installations up in `preinst` (which can have unfortunate consequences).